# What is a positive question record?

Tags: discussion, badges

The question says it all:

What is a positive question record? You need this for the Curious badge, so what is it?

Comment: This seems slightly silly, but does Oli mean that you need to post 5 questions on 5 seperate days with a score of over or equal to 1, or a score of over or equal to 0?

Comment: Pretty sure it is >= 1.

Comment: Ok. I'll do the "That solved my problem!"